# How to solve this partial differential equation $\partial_s^2 y + \partial_ty + y = 0$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm working on the following exercise on multiple-scale perturbation of

> $\varepsilon y'' + y' + y = 0$ with $y(0)=0, y'(0)=1$

and the following PDE came up (we consider $y = y(t,s)$ because of the multiple-scale analysis):

$$\partial_s^2 y + \partial_ty + y = 0.$$

I know virtually nothing about PDEs and googling didn't help to solve it.

As far as I can see, we'd need to rewrite it as $$\partial_s^2 y + y = -\partial_ty$$ then $$y_h = A(t)\sin(s)+B(t)\cos(s)$$ would be the homogeneous solution.

If the above makes sense, what is a particular solution?

Comment: A simple way to a particular solution is to require that it depend only on $t$. This immediately gives $y_p = C e^{-t}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $u=e^t\,y$. Then $u$ satisfies the equation
$$
\partial_{ss}u+\partial_tu=0.
$$
This is a backwards in time heat equation. You can find particular solutions of the form
$$
u(s,t)=S(s)\,T(t).
$$
Since the equation is linear and homogeneous, any linear combination of such solutions is also a solution.